# In jQuery how can I correctly use a selector as var in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a variable in my selector when applied to dynamically created div's (from an XML file) in a for loop. The previewDialog is only opening when I click on the very last div. How do I get the previewDialog to open when I click on EACH overview div?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "Library.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

var f = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FeaturedEntry");
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("BookEntry");
for (b = 0; b < x.length; b++) {

  var bToString = b.toString();
  var overviewOpener = "#overview" + bToString;
  var previewDialog = "#preview" + bToString;

  // increase the default animation speed to exaggerate the effect
  $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
  $(function () {
    $(previewDialog).dialog({
      autoOpen : false,
      show : "blind",
      hide : "explode"
    });

    $(overviewOpener).click(function () {
      $(previewDialog).dialog("open");
      return false;
    });

  });

  document.write(overviewOpener + " " + b.value + " " + bToString);
  document.write("<div id='overview");
  document.write(b);
  document.write("'><img id='cover' src='/ClientBin/");
  icon = x[b].getAttribute("Icon");
  document.write(icon);
  document.write("'/><br><strong><a href='http://www.google.com'>");
  title = x[b].getAttribute("Title");
  document.write(title);
  document.write("</a></strong><br>");
  author = x[b].getAttribute("Author");
  document.write(author);
  document.write("<br>");
  document.write("Rating:");
  rating = x[b].getAttribute("Rating");
  numStars = Math.round(rating * 5);
  for (n = 0; n < numStars; n++) {
    document.write("<img src='/Media/star.png'/>");
  }
  document.write("<br><a><img id='button' src='Media/Small_iBookstore_Badge.gif' /></a>");
  document.write("</div>");

  document.write("<div id='preview");
  document.write(b);
  document.write("'>This is a test ");
  document.write(b);
  document.write("</div>");

}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Rachel - this is a gruesome bit of code with a lot of anti-pattern going on in it. I hate to be the bearer of bad news, i would recommend first triaging this by creating useful functions. This will allow you to better debug your processes and thought as you work through this. I only say this because it is obvious you are keen enough to see where the error lies. Good luck.

Comment: I assume the jQuery portion of this is new to you? Seeing the original AJAX building method (as opposed to `$.ajax`) and `document.getElementsByTagName` (as opposed to `$('tagname')`) is...different to say the least)

Comment: jQuery's document.ready method (`$(function() {`) should not be called in a for loop. It is considered [bad practice](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/55) to create functions in for loops. Also you should add `var` in front of your variable `b` inside the foor loop declaration.

Comment: I realize my code is messy... I'm not a programmer by trade (graphic and UI/web designer by experience not training) and have learned everything I know on my own. I saw a similar problem someone else was having but didn't quite know if their solution would work for me or how to implement it. Here's the link: <http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/9766/jquery-selector-div-variable/p1>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closures my friend. Closures. The problem is that  `$(function () {` isn't executed inline like you think it is, it's executed when the DOM loads. But your `var b` is OUTSIDE of the `$(function)` call, which means when this function is called, it will pick up the *current* version of b, which is why you see it only works for the last one. You need to take your $(function) completely outside your for loop and then do something like this:

```
$(function () {
  //add the for loop here 
    for (var b = 0; b < x.length; b++) {
        $("#preview" + b).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "blind",
            hide: "explode"
        });

        $("#overview" + b).click(function () {
            $("#preview" + b).dialog("open");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Having said that. You're still doing it the wrong way. A loop like this is not the right way to do it either. What you should REALLY do is instead of this:

```
document.write("<div id='preview");
    document.write(b);
    document.write("'>This is a test ");
    document.write(b);
    document.write("</div>");
```

Do this:

```
document.write("<div class='preview'>This is a test ");
    document.write(b);
    document.write("</div>");
```

See how we've given each div the same class of "preview?"

Now you can just do this:

```
$(function () {
      //no for loop needed now
            $(".preview").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                show: "blind",
                hide: "explode"
            });
```

*Edited*: You're right, you *do* need to have a unique name for each div, but not exactly for the reason you think. The reason is because the jQuery UI Dialog moves the element to the top of the DOM. Originally, I was thinking you would do something like:

`$(".overview").closest(".SomeContainerDiv").find(".preview")`.... But unfortunately, in this case (because the div is moved), you can't do that. Take a look at this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ehs4K/

Comment: I tried the first solution of putting the function outside of the loop and it didn't work. On the second comment referring to the "preview" div, I need to have unique div's because each popup/dialogue div will have unique content.

Comment: You're a genius! That worked! I figured it needed an each function because of other solutions I found but wasn't quite sure how to implement it. Thanks a million! :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't go through the entire code but from what I could understand the overview  div is created dynamically.For dynamicaly created elements you have to use

```
$(overviewOpener).live("click",function(){
//hanfle click function});
```

Comment: You should use `$.on` instead of `$.bind`, `$.live` or `$.click`